# Custom Views in Swift2

Tags: uiview, storyboard, swift2, ios9

I have a Custom view that is a subClass of UIView . I want to show its properties on storyBoard Inspector Panel So that it can be edited directly from StoryBoard in future . An Example

```
class CustomView : UIView {
  // This Property should be editable via StoryBoard
  var Color : UIColor = UIColor().greenColor()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to do it:

http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

```
class CustomView : UIView {
  @IBInspectable // Add this line
  var Color : UIColor = UIColor().greenColor()
}
```

Comment: Wow thats it? So Cool Man!